# How to combine an Observable of a sequence with an Observable of a single value and then flatten this structure

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I want to find the best way possible to combine two functions that returns Observables.

The first function is defined as follows:

```js
abstract getProfiles(): Observable<ClientProfile[]>
```

the second one is:

```js
abstract getUser(userId: number): Observable<User>
```

I want to create a projection in order to create a data structure like this:

```js
interface Projection {
  user: User,
  profiles: ClientProfile[]
}
```

in order to do that I would like to optimise this function

```js
getUserProfiles() {
  this.userService.getProfiles()
    .pipe(
      flatMap((ps: ClientProfile[]) => {
         ps.map(p => this.userService.getUser(p.userId))
         // I NEED TO RETURN AN OBSERVABLE HERE:
         // {user: u, ...ps}
      })
    )
    .subscribe(_ => doSomething(_))
```

What's the best way to do merge a single user into the list of profiles?

Comment: Your Projection interface doesn't make sense to me. Aren't User and ClientProfile in 1 on 1 relationship?

Comment: A `User` can be linked to many `ClientProfile` [1-N].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest combining the `mergeMap` and `forkJoin` operators.

```
import {map as rxMap, mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';

this.userService.getProfiles().pipe(
    mergeMap(profiles =>
        forkJoin(profiles.map(profile =>
            this.userService.getUser(profile.userId).pipe(
                rxMap(user =>
                    ({
                        user,
                        profiles
                    })
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The profiles list is being mapped to an `Array<Observable<{user, profile}>>`.
These observables are completing (from the `userService`) when the http request returns.

`ForkJoin` waits for these observables to complete and then emits an observable containing these completed values. MergeMap unwraps this observable by merging the inner observable created by `getUser()` into the outer observable from `getProfiles()`.

Comment: So far, this is the most clever approach I've seen, and I guess that's what I was looking for. So `ForkJoin` waits for `getUser()` to emit a value, that is mapped to the `{user, profiles}` and then the results are flattened by `flatMap`. I will test your solution and if it works I'll accept it. ;)

Comment: I approved your answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switchMap` to return an array of Observables of `getUser()` API like this:

```
getUserProfiles() {
    this.userService.getProfiles()
      .pipe(
        switchMap((ps: ClientProfile[]) => {
           const obs$ = ps.map(p => {
              return this.userService.getUser(p.userId)
                         .pipe(
                           map(user => ({user, profile: ps}))
                         );
           });

           return obs$;
           // I NEED TO RETURN AN OBSERVABLE HERE:
           // {user: u, ...ps}
        }),
        switchMap(x => x)
      )
      .subscribe(_ => doSomething(_))
```

Above solution will work fine if you do not want to wait for all the getUser() API to be finished. i.e. On subscribe you would process each emission of getUser() API response (which is projected with {user, profile}).

If you want to wait for all the getUser() API to be finished then use `forkJoin()` like this:

```
getUserProfiles() {
    this.userService.getProfiles()
      .pipe(
        switchMap((ps: ClientProfile[]) => {
           const obs$ = ps.map(p => {
              return this.userService.getUser(p.userId)
                         .pipe(
                           map(user => ({user, profile: ps}))
                         );
           });

           return forkJoin(obs$);
           // I NEED TO RETURN AN OBSERVABLE HERE:
           // {user: u, ...ps}
        }),
        tap(result => //result will be an array of {user, profile})
      )
      .subscribe(_ => doSomething(_))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you:

```
function solving() {
    interface Profile {
        id: number, name: string, userId: number
    }
    interface User {
        id: number, username: string
    }

    const getProfiles = () => ajax('api/profiles').pipe(
        pluck<AjaxResponse, Array<Profile>>('response')
    );

    const getUser = (id: number) => ajax(`api/users/${id}`).pipe(
        pluck<AjaxResponse, User>('response')
    );

    getProfiles().pipe(
        concatMap(perfils => from(perfils).pipe(map(p => [p, perfils]))),
        mergeMap(([p, perfils]: [Profile, Profile[]]) => 
                        getUser(p.userId).pipe(map(u => [u, perfils])))
    ).subscribe(console.log);
}
```