# Nested mergeMap+forkJoin combinations

Tags: angular, rxjs, nested

I'm working with data of the form `tool > feature > view`. In other words, there are tools, a tool has features, a feature has views.

In Angular 2 (13), I'm using a service to handle http calls to fetch data. When the app starts, a resolver triggers the setting of the service's `tools` array property by calling the service's `setTools()` method. This method should build `tools` by fetching the tools, then populating each tool with features, which are each populated with views, all via nested http calls for each part.

I found an [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56809220/10950068) using a combination of `mergeMap` and `forkJoin` (from rxjs) that achieves this down a single layer. I then implemented the following in the service:

```
setTools(): Observable<Tool[]> {
  return this.getTools().pipe(
    mergeMap(tools =>
      forkJoin<Tool[]>(
        tools.map(tool =>
          this.getFeatures(tool.id).pipe(
            map(features => ({ ...tool, features })
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    tap<Tool[]>(tools => console.log(tools))
  )
}
```

This works correctly. Tools are printed out, each containing its respective features. Great!

Naively, I implemented the following to achieve the next layer of population, i.e. views:

```
setTools(): Observable<Tool[]> {
  return this.getTools().pipe(
    mergeMap(tools =>
      forkJoin<Tool[]>(
        tools.map(tool =>
          this.getFeatures(tool.id).pipe(
            mergeMap(features =>
              forkJoin<Feature[]>(
                features.map(feature =>
                  this.getViews(feature.id).pipe(
                    map(views => ({ ...feature, views })
                  )
                )
              )
            ),
            map(features => ({ ...tool, features })
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    tap<Tool[]>(tools => console.log(tools))
  )
}
```

However, tools no longer log out to console. Why? What am I doing wrong? Also, if there is another way to implement this, I'll greatly appreciate the input. FYI, I'm quite new to web development.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get your example to work without more code/types, so I've changed the approach slightly and might not answer the question completely. Using mergeMap with mergeAll and to Array gives the nested structure.

```
  setTools() {
    return this.getTools().pipe(
      mergeAll(),
      mergeMap(tool =>
        this.getFeatures(tool.id).pipe(
          mergeAll(),
          mergeMap(feature=>
             this.getViews(feature.id).pipe(
                 map((views) => ({...feature, views }))
             )
          ),
          toArray(),
          map((features)=>({...tool, features}))
        )
      ),
      toArray(),
    );
  }
```

See stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ee1myv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I've just separated out your code into a few separate functions. It runs just fine for me on a minimalist harness. Basically no changes...

```ts
embellishFeature(feature){
  return this.getViews(feature.id).pipe(
    map(views => ({...feature, views}))
  );
}

embellishFeatures(features){
  return forkJoin(features.map(v => this.embellishFeature(v)));
}

embellishTool(tool){
  return this.getFeatures(tool.id).pipe(
    mergeMap(v => this.embellishFeatures(v)),
    map(features => ({...tool, features}))
  );
}

embellishTools(tools){
  return forkJoin(tools.map(v => this.embellishTool(v)));
}

setTools(): Observable<Tool[]> {
  return this.getTools().pipe(
    mergeMap(v => this.embellishTools(v)),
    tap(tools => console.log(tools))
  );
}
```